# tcpdf with writeHTMLCell and style embeds fonts twice

Tags: fonts, tcpdf

I add a TTF Font and use full embedding without subsetting.

```
$pdf->addTTFfont('MetaOT-Bold.ttf', '',  '', 32);
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(FALSE);
```

When I use this font directly, the font is embedded once as expected.

```
$pdf->SetFont('metaotb','', 16);
$html = "Hello World";
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 5, 0, 0, $html,0 ,1);
```

Acrobat tells me of one embedded font, called *MetaOT_Bold (embedded)*.

But when I use this via stylesheet instead, the problem occurs:

```
$pdf->SetFont('metaotb','', 16);
$html = "<style> b { font-family: metaotb; }</style>";
$html .= "<b>Hello World</b>";
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 5, 0, 0, $html,0 ,1);
```

Now Acrobat tells me of **two** embedded font, one called *MetaOT_Bold (embedded)*, the other called *MetaOT_Bold,Bold (embedded)*.

It is a problem, as I can't use this pdf for further processing. My system obviously doesn't know the second font (as it doesn't exist). Any ideas?

Comment: I think the second one is just a reference, but be wrong... Is there any difference in file size?

Comment: There actually is a small difference in size.
TestWithStyleBold.pdf is 142.394 Bytes
TestWithDirectBold.pdf is 139.562 Bytes

The main problem is further processing (in my case a Illustrator batch to convert all text to outlines) - Illustrator tells me about non-recognized font...

Comment: What happens when you remove `SetFont` from the second example? Normally, I `addTTFFont` and then reference the font **only** in the stylesheet. That said, I'm not entirely sure whats going on here - might be worth [submitting an issue over at Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/p/tcpdf/bugs/).